# Else statement not working in javascript (only returning if and if else)

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the JavaScript project where you make a simple rock paper scissors game and I can't seem to figure out why my code only returns "player wins" even when player is supposed to lose. Here's the code:

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
console.log("Player: " + userChoice)

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice)

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock"
} else if (computerChoice > 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper"
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors"
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  var x = userChoice
  var y = computerChoice
  if (x === y) {
    return "The result is a tie!"
  }
  if (x === "rock", y === "scissors") {
    return "player wins"
  } else if (x === "scissors", y === "paper") {
    return "player wins"
  } else if (x === "paper", y === "rock") {
    return "player wins"
  } else {
    return "You lose"
  }
}

compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

Also on a side note, why does the console on stackoverflow not show the return when the console on codeacademy does.

Comment: the issue is with if condition use logical operators instead of **,**. like **x === 5 || y ===3**

Comment: unfortunately I'm nowhere near good enough with python for that looks interesting though

Comment: Do not add comments to your question. Put comments in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the operator `&&` and not a `,`.

```
var compare = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  var x = userChoice;
  var y = computerChoice;

  if (x === y) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }
  if (x === "rock" && y === "scissors") {
    return "player wins";
  } else if (x === "scissors" && y === "paper") {
    return "player wins";
  } else if (x === "paper" && y === "rock") {
    return "player wins";
  } else {
    return "You lose";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you lost something, maybe you should change :

```
if (x === "rock", y === "scissors") {
```

to

```
if (x === "rock" && y === "scissors") {
```

Other conditional statements should do that like above.